# Putting things into NSMutableArray and using it

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'd like to use a NSMutableArray and then use its contents. My code is below:

```
[_sizedWordList addObject:[_wordList objectAtIndex:i]];


UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:[_sizedWordList objectAtIndex:0] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

Where _sizedWordList is a `NSMutableArray` and _wordList is `NSArray`. For some reason the alert isn't showing.

Comment: Does it show if you put in some static strings instead of the contents of your array?

Comment: @Nick No. Even if I said `[_sizedWordList addObject:@"hello"];` and tried to display then it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try something like this `[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"A message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];` ?

Comment: I've posted a working example, can you show us how you declared the array?

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the help. I first used `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sizedWordList;` in the .h file then `@synthesize sizedWordList = _sizedWordList;` in the .m file

Comment: And how did you initialize it?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the init line and run in the debugger.  When it stops at the breakpoint, check if `_sizedWordList` is null.  If it is, there's your problem, you haven't created it.

Comment: @Nick @JeremyP hm, doesn't `@synthesize` initialize it?

Comment: No a synthesize will actually create getter and setter methods for you for that property. You can initialize your array like this: `self.sizedWordList = [NSMutableArray array];`. Don't forget to use the dot syntax, the setter will retain the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, then there must be something wrong with your array. Look, I've created this small working example.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

[myArray addObject:@"Hello everybody"];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
                                                message:[myArray objectAtIndex:0] 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```